# Laravel 5 Sitemap: not found

Tags: php, laravel

```
exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Watson\Sitemap\SitemapServiceProvider' not found' in
```

I'm trying to apply Watson Package for generating sitemap.  But I saw that error. I cannot understand why that class is not found.

Vendor\watson\sitemap... everything seems there.

The problem is increased with every new package and could not explain to myself..

I tried composer dump-autoload... php artisan optimized...

Thank you...

Comment: You really need to add more information. What version of Laravel? What version of Watson Package? Have you added the the **service provider** and **alias** to your app/config/app.php file? How are you attempting to use it?

Comment: Laravel 5,     "watson/sitemap": "2.0.*", Yes, I added service provider and alias. What is the path of steps when add package? It added files in vendor and new config file (in my case: sitemap)... what else?

Comment: Tell us how you are using it, show your controller code. Are you including a `use` statement, if so what is it?

Comment: After published the package I could see blank page (broke my website) and when I checked Laravel Logs you can see the error (my 1st post). Obviously, could not find that package.

Comment: So you haven't tried to use it? your not invoking it from a controller? You literally just installed the package via composer and now your entire site is showing a blank page?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And error exists in laravel logs. That the reason to broke my website.

Comment: I found it. Just any file or files did not uploaded...and the class was unfoundable, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 5.1 the way you add service providers to your app/config/app.php file has changed slightly.

Instead of using:

```
'Watson\Sitemap\SitemapServiceProvider'
```

Try using:

```
Watson\Sitemap\SitemapServiceProvider::class,
```

Comment: I'm using 5.0. All services are defined in same way. I don't think it is the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Then why did you accept it as the answer? If you solved the problem add your own answer so that people with the same problem in the future can solve it too.